# structure in template class

Tags: c++

sample code is as follow:

```
struct TEMP
{
    int j;
    TEMP()
    {
     j = 0;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class classA
{
    struct strA
    {
        long i;
        strA():i(0) {}
    };
    static strA obj_str;
    classA();
};

template<typename T>
classA<T>::classA()
{}

template<typename T> 
classA<TEMP>::strA classA<TEMP>::obj_str;

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

while compiling this code, I am getting following error:

> test1.cpp:32: internal compiler error: in import_export_decl, at cp/decl2.c:1970
>   Please submit a full bug report,
>   with preprocessed source if appropriate.
>   See http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
>   Preprocessed source stored into /tmp/ccUGE0GW.out file, please attach this to your bugreport.

I am building this code at x86_64-redhat-linux machine, and gcc version is gcc version 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)

Please note this code was already built with gcc version 3.4.5 20051201 (Red Hat 3.4.5-2) at i386-redhat-linux machine.

Any idea why this is not able to build with gcc 4.1.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you submit a full bug report?  That's what the error tells you to do.  You can try using a different compiler [version] for now.

Comment: Found a bug report here: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24791 - this looks like a variant of that one.

Comment: An internal compiler error always means something is wrong with the compiler, so don't take it to mean this is your fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any case, your code doesn't make much sense in the following declaration.

```
template<typename T> 
classA<TEMP>::strA classA<TEMP>::obj_str;
```

Because the `T` parameter is used nowhere in the declaration. I think you either wanted to write one of the following things:

```
// definition of static member of template
template<typename T> 
typename classA<T>::strA classA<T>::obj_str;

// ... or declaration of static member specialization for `T=TEMP` of template
template<> 
classA<TEMP>::strA classA<TEMP>::obj_str;
```

I suspect it was the first one. For the compiler crash - that surely shouldn't happen in any case :)

---

**Edit:** The bug has already been fixed in 4.4.1 at least - i think there is no need for reporting anymore.

Comment: Right, this kind of bug has been reported and fixed in higher version already. But I was thinking that If it is possible to build it with same version and with some code change.  

And yes, with above code change, code gets compiled.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the error report.